# What's the difference between というものではない、というものでもない and というわけがない?

Tags: grammar

I often encounter these three forms, but I'm sure that they are not always interchangeable. Someone could explain me the difference and perhaps provide me some example too?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently they are covered regularly in foreigners' grammar e.g. [this](https://nihongonosensei.net/?p=12824) or [this](https://nihongokyoshi-net.com/2018/05/08/jlptn2-grammar-toiumonodewanai/). I assume you meant というわけではない for the third item.

All three can be translated mostly *It is not that ...*.

Just one example:

- 謝ればいいというものではない : It is not that saying sorry is enough.
- 謝ればいいというものでもない : It is not really that saying sorry is enough.

The former sounds a bit stronger denial/disagreement for 'saying sorry is enough', somewhat suggesting something else must be done. The latter sounds softer, like *saying sorry should not be enough, but maybe nothing else should be done either*.

というわけではない/というわけでもない are mostly synonymous to というものではない/というものでもない, but like covered [here](https://chiyo-sampo.net/grammar-jlptn2-toiu-wakedewanai-2/), in a structure with preceding ～だからといって, というわけで{は,も}ない may be more frequent. (～だからといって～というもので{は,も}ない is possible).

===

わけない appears as form of [～わけがない](https://nihongokyoshi-net.com/2018/04/16/jlptn2-grammar-wakeganai/), where が is omitted. Means *it is impossible that...*.

Answer (score 0):

For what i know, the first one mean "is not", the second one "Not even" and the third one "There is no reason". They should be used in different context